# Asp.Net Azure Cloud - Getting files size takes long time

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud

I want to get the sum of sizes of all the files under various child folders available under a parent folder.

I get the size but it takes around 15 seconds to calculate the results.

Here is the code:

```
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connectionString");
var fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
var cloudFileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference("shareName");
var rootDirectory = cloudFileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
var directory = rootDirectory.GetDirectoryReference("folderName");

var size = directory.ListFilesAndDirectories().Select(x => (CloudFileDirectory)x).SelectMany(x => x.ListFilesAndDirectories()).Sum(x => ((CloudFile)x).Properties.Length);
```

Can I optimize it further to get the size quickly.

**Edit 1:**

**Testings:**

- Scenario 1: More folders with more or less files
- Scenario 2: Less folders with more or less files

**Findings:**

- It takes long time when the folders count is more, irrespective of the files
  count (could be more or less)
- It works fine when the folders count is less, irrespective of the files count (could be more or less)

Answer (score 0):

Examining your LINQ query:

```
var size = directory
           .ListFilesAndDirectories()
           .Select(x => (CloudFileDirectory)x)
           .SelectMany(x => x.ListFilesAndDirectories())
           .Sum(x => ((CloudFile)x).Properties.Length);
```

I can see some initial problems. Firstly this assumes only directories will exist on the first level inside the root directory. This can be seen with the casting `(CloudFileDirectory)x`. This will raise an exception if a `CloudFile` is found instead. A scalable solution should handle both types of files. Secondly, this query also assumes only files will exist inside each child directory, hence the `(CloudFile)x` casting. This means that this will only go one level deep inside the child directories, and will not recurse through any sub directories. This will also raise an exception if any sub directories are found instead. I have outlined some more scalable approaches below.

**Solution 1:**

Use [`CloudFileDirectory.ListFilesAndDirectories()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.file.cloudfiledirectory.listfilesanddirectories?view=azure-dotnet-legacy), which combines all files into a `IEnumerable<IListFileItem>`. Recursively go through each item and sum up the btyes found if a file is found, or recurse if a directory is found.

```
public static void FileShareByteCount(CloudFileDirectory directory, ref long bytesCount)
{
    if (directory == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("directory", "Directory cannot be null");
    }

    var files = directory.ListFilesAndDirectories();

    foreach (var item in files)
    {
        if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudFileDirectory))
        {
            var cloudFileDirectory = item as CloudFileDirectory;
            FileShareByteCount(cloudFileDirectory, ref bytesCount);
        }
        else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudFile))
        {
            var cloudFile = item as CloudFile;
            bytesCount += cloudFile.Properties.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage 1:**

```
long bytesCount = 0;
FileShareByteCount(sampleDir, ref bytesCount);
Console.WriteLine($"Current file share usage: {bytesCount}");
```

**Solution 2:**

Go through the fileshare in batches using [`CloudFileDirectory.ListFilesAndDirectoriesSegmented()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.file.cloudfiledirectory.listfilesanddirectoriessegmented?view=azure-dotnet-legacy), which allows you to specify the number of files to be returned per `IEnumerable<IListFileItem>` segment. Same as above, recursively go through each item and sum up the btyes found if a file is found, or recurse if a directory is found.

```
public static void FileShareByteCount(CloudFileDirectory directory, int? maxResults, ref long bytesCount)
{
    if (directory == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("directory", "Directory cannot be null");
    }

    FileContinuationToken continuationToken = null;

    do
    {
        var resultSegment = directory.ListFilesAndDirectoriesSegmented(maxResults, continuationToken, null, null);

        var results = resultSegment.Results;

        if (results.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudFileDirectory))
                {
                    var cloudFileDirectory = item as CloudFileDirectory;
                    FileShareByteCount(cloudFileDirectory, maxResults, ref bytesCount);
                }
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudFile))
                {
                    var cloudFile = item as CloudFile;
                    bytesCount += cloudFile.Properties.Length;
                }
            }
        }

        continuationToken = resultSegment.ContinuationToken;

    } while (continuationToken != null);
}
```

**Usage 2:**

```
long bytesCount = 0;
FileShareByteCount(directory, 100, ref bytesCount);
Console.WriteLine($"Current file share usage: {bytesCount}");
```

**Note:** You can specifiy the max size of the segments with `maxResults`. The Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.file.cloudfiledirectory.listfilesanddirectoriessegmented?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) states:

> A non-negative integer value that indicates the maximum number of results to be returned at a time, up to the per-operation limit of 5000. If this value is null, the maximum possible number of results will be returned, up to 5000.

Comment: This solution took around 18 seconds in above case. :(

Comment: @ReyanChougle Hmm, did you try increasing /decreasing the `maxResult` size? I gave `100` as an example but that might not be the best batch size.

Comment: Again no improvements in response time

Comment: @ReyanChougle Sorry, I tried to help. Looks like no one else has answered so your original LINQ query is probably the best. The only suggestion is that its not a very safe query because it relies on only child directories existing in the parent directory. If any lone files exist in `directory` it will raise an exception. This is because it casts to `(CloudFileDirectory)x`, but what if a `CloudFile` exists? It also probably wont be able to go many levels deep as well, which is why a recursive solution like the above works well, despite it being slower.

Comment: Thanks for your time and I absolutely agree on the points you suggested above. But I had to write the LINQ query this way because of our business requirements

Comment: @ReyanChougle. No worries, thats understandable. Out of curiosity, could you have a test of the first solution above as well? I updated my answer to show a similar approach using `ListFilesAndDirectories`. I'm investigating if there is any actual peformance benefit in using `ListFilesAndDirectoriesSegmented`. I don't have many files in my Azure File share at the moment, so any major performance increase/decrease is hard to see.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I tried both the above solutions as well as my LINQ query again, all of them took long and same amount of time. I have updated my findings in question

Comment: @ReyanChougle Only recommendation I can make is to use paralleization. That might speed this up a bit. Just have to make sure the code is thread safe. Something like: `directory.AsParallel().ListFilesAndDirectories().Select(x => (CloudFileDirectory)x).SelectMany(x => x.ListFilesAndDirectories()).Sum(x => ((CloudFile)x).Properties.Length);`